# Can docker-compose directly reference other docker-compose files and start everything in them?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few docker-compose files, such as:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  my_other_service:
    image: alpine
    command: ping -c3 google.com
  my_base_service_reference:
    extends:
      file: base-docker-compose.yml
      service: base_service

#base-docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  base_service:
    image: alpine
    command: ping -c5 google.com
```

I can run both these services with just `docker-compose up` because I am referencing the second file. But what I really would like to do is make my single docker-compose file work like the way this works:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  my_other_service:
    image: alpine
    command: ping -c3 google.com
#base-docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  base_service:
    image: alpine
    command: ping -c5 google.com

$ docker-compose -f base-docker-compose.yml up &
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up &
```

Is there a way to construct my docker-compose.yml in such a way to get similar functionality?

In reality I have a lot more than two simple examples and it'd be nice to avoid having to launch each separate service and it's required dependencies individually but rather something like:

```
#docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  my_other_service:
    image: alpine
    command: ping -c3 google.com

other_docker_compose_files: 
  - base-docker-compose.yml
  - other-docker-compose.yml
  - another-docker-compose.yml
```

where I could just run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` and do the equivalent of starting each of those files individually.

Answer (score 0):

Even after 5 years, docker-compose has no ability to do things like this or `docker-compose up -f docker-compose*.yml`.

I would advise all people to use [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), and use it to merge all yaml files into one.

I use a script like this, the first line is just to make sure there are no leftovers and can be removed.

**run_all.sh**

```bash
rm docker-compose-combined.yml
yq ea '. as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item )' docker-compose*.yml > docker-compose-combined.yml
docker-compose -f docker-compose-combined.yml up
rm docker-compose-combined.yml
```